# How to move an object using X and Y coordinates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I am making a 2-Dimensional baseball game with JavaScript and HTML5 and I am trying to move an image that I have drawn with JavaScript like so:

```
//canvas
var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//baseball
var baseball = new Image();
baseball.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(baseball, 400, 425);
};
baseball.src = "baseball2.png";
```

I'm not sure how I would move it though, I have seen many people seem to just type something like `ballX` and `ballY` but I don't understand where the actual `x` and `y` definition comes from. Here is my code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/xRfua/

Thanks in advance for any help at all!

Comment: Keep track of the `x` and `y` position and translate based on these values before drawing your image: `ctx.save(); ctx.translate(xpos, ypos); ctx.restore();`

Comment: Declare two variables called something like `xpos` and `ypos`. These can be updated either using a timer or perhaps when the user presses the right or left arrow on the keyboard. Then when rendering you first save your context, then translate based on `xpos` and `ypos`, draw your image and finally restore the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the balls position in a couple of variables and then you can translate based on these values before drawing your object, something like this should work:

```
var baseballX = 0;
var baseballY = 0;
var goLeft = 0;
var goRight = 0;
var goUp = 0;
var goDown = 0;
var ballSpeed = 5;

function renderCanvas() {
   // clear the canvas
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
   ctx.save();

   if(goLeft) baseballX -= ballSpeed;
   if(goRight) baseballX += ballSpeed;
   if(goUp) baseballY -= ballSpeed;
   if(goDown) baseballY += ballSpeed;

   // translate to balls position
   ctx.translate(baseballX, baseballY);
   // draw the image
   ctx.drawImage(baseball, 0, 0);
   ctx.restore();
}

// handle any user input
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
   switch (event.keyCode) {
     case 37: // Left
       goLeft = 0;
     break;
     case 38: // Up
       goUp = 0;
     break;
     case 39: // Right
       goRight = 0;
     break;
     case 40: // Down
       goDown = 0;
     break;
   }
 }, false);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
   switch (event.keyCode) {
     case 37: // Left
       goLeft = 1;
     break;
     case 38: // Up
       goUp = 1;
     break;
     case 39: // Right
       goRight = 1;
     break;
     case 40: // Down
       goDown = 1;
     break;
   }
 }, false);

// set off timer
setInterval(renderCanvas, 1000 / 100);
```

Here is a working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xRfua/5/)

Comment: The fiddle example has an invalid / stale link for the baseball src url.  You can use this one or find one from google images that's about 150 x 150:  https://www.bergino.com/v/vspfiles/photos/10123-2T.jpg

Comment: Not sure how important this is? The question is about how to move the object which is not really related to the graphic.

Comment: In the fiddle code, you can't see the operation without the graphic.  It shows up as a blank white screen.  If you use a valid graphic image, then you can see the code work